# Why does writing the code in this order still work?

Tags: python

I'm fairly new to coding and I'm just trying to make an function that does exponents.
My code was this:

```
base_n = int(input("Enter an integer as your base number: "))
exp = int(input("Enter an integer as your exponent: "))

def raise_to_power(base_n, exp):
    result = 1
    # Loop as many times as exp
    for index in range(exp):
        result = result * base_n
    return result

result = raise_to_power(base_n, exp)

print(result)
```

It works out great but I'm wondering why writing it in this order still works just as well:

```
def raise_to_power(base_n, exp):
    result = 1
    # Loop as many times as exp
    for index in range(exp):
        result = result * base_n
    return result

base_n = int(input("Enter an integer as your base number: "))
exp = int(input("Enter an integer as your exponent: "))
result = raise_to_power(base_n, exp)

print(result)
```

Why does the function still work when I asked the user after the function. Shouldn't the function stop working after the computer reads it. After all, the variables are in the lines below the function, which means they get read after the function right? And how does the function still work  if the variables its using doesn't even have data in them yet?

Comment: `def raise_to_power(base_n, exp):` code is just the definition of a function, it doesn't actually run that code until the function is called (which you do in `result = raise_to_power(base_n, exp)`. So long your function definition is **before** you call that function, it will work.

Comment: As long as you define a function before calling it and the function does not rely on global variables defined after any order is fine. In your case your function gets add the data it needs from it's arguments.

Comment: Move your function ```def raise_to_power(base_n, exp):``` to the end and see what happens when you run it. You will clearly understand what @dm2 said.

Comment: You used `input` after the `input` function was created too. The `input` function didn't know what data you were going to give it in advance either.

Comment: wp-overwatch.com could you elaborate please?